# Grabbing a number from .JSON

Tags: json, regex, node.js

I have a long list of data, in the following format:

```
[
{
    "ID": "1234",
    "date/time": "2016-07-18 18:21:44",
    "source_address": "8011",
    "lat": "40.585260",
    "lng": "-105.084420",
}
]
```

And I am creating a script to extract the values out of each line. For example, if a line contains "ID": I want to be able to store the value "1234" into a variable, so I can store it in a different format.

Here is my code to detect "ID":

```
'use strict';

let lineReader = require('line-reader');

//.JSON variables from input file
let id;


//begin creating new object
console.log('var source = {');
//output the file
lineReader.eachLine('dataOut.json', function (line, last) {

    //detect ID, and print it out in the new format
    if (id =~ /^id:$/) {
        console.log('id: "') + console.log('",');
    }

    //done
    if (last) {
        console.log('}');
        return false; // stop reading
    }
});
```

Once I detect the ID, I'm not sure how I can obtain the value that follows the "ID" on that line.

How can I store the values on a line, after I detect which line they are on?

Comment: you don't "grab from json". you decode the json, and then it becomes a plain old javascript data structure, like any other.

Comment: Thanks! Sorry to ask, but do you have some sort of example I can look at, to get a better idea of how to implement what you are saying?

Comment: The example is in any discussion of `JSON.parse`, or of how to access properties in JavaScript objects, and/or how to `require` JSON from a node program.

Comment: BTW if you're writing in node, then `id =~ /^id:$/` is not going to work at all, unless node just hooked with Perl and they had an illegitimate child.

Comment: whoops, I didn't test that before I entered it. Old habits! Thanks again

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Unless your json file is stupidly big, you can just require it and then it's an in memory JS object.

```
var obj = require('./dataOut.json');

// first element
console.log(obj[0]);
```

Comment: interesting! I had no idea this could be done, my json isn't that big so this may work